# What are the best practices in sql to find the last leaf of a category?

Tags: sql, database, jpa, join, mariadb

Category exists in poi, and parent_id exists in category.

At this time, I wonder how to find the last leaf of the poi.

```
select
     p.*
from
     TB_CATEGORY last,
     tb_poi p
left outer join tb_category mid
left outer join tb_category first
where
     last.id = p.CATEGORY_ID
and
     last.PARENT_ID = mid.id
and
     mid.parent_id = first.ID
and
     first. parent_id is null
and
     first.id = 1
```

In this way, the first of tb_category is 1 and the last.id is p.category_id by writing sql to import all leafs.

What I'm curious about here is what's a better best practice than this?

Comment: Could you maybe add a simple DDL for the problem along with the sample data and the desired outcome based on the sample, please?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use standard SQL, instead of the MariaDB extension of joins without predicates.